# criando campo de nota/observação

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber como é criado esses campos, eu criei um exemplo, mas não sei se realmente é assim que ele é criado. Segue exemplo do que eu criei:

```css
.nota {
         background-color: #CCC;
            width: 500px;
            height: 50px;
            font-family: tahoma, arial;
            font-weight: 100;
}
.cor-inicio-nota {
         background-color: #0F0; 
            width: 5px;
            height: 50px;
            float: left;
}
.texto-nota {
         width: 495px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #FF0;
            display: inline-block;
            text-indent: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>teste</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nota">
       <div class="cor-inicio-nota"> 
       </div>
        <div class="texto-nota">
         <p><b>Nota:</b> observações importantes irão aqui...</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Teria como reduzir a quantidade de código e obter esse mesmo efeito?

Comment: pensei na hipótese de deixar apenas duas _div_, a _div_ `.texto-nota` contida dentro da _div_ `.nota` e aplicar na _div_ `.texto-nota` um `float-right` nela e definir a cor de fundo da _div_ que a contem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem 'n' maneiras, se estiver pensando somente na questão visual, pode utilizar um `border-left` para colocar aquele verde na esquerda.

```css
div {
  background: #FF0;
  border-left: 5px solid #0F0;
  font-family: tahoma, arial;
  padding: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <b>Nota:</b> observações importantes irão aqui...
</div>
```

Comment: cara, isso reduziu consideravelmente e obtive o mesmo resultado. Era exatamente isso!

Comment: Muito massa, mas ainda dava para tirar uma linha de CSS, e não é o font-family :)

Answer (score 2):

A opção de redução de código é utilizar o `linear-gradient`:

```css
.nota{
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0F0 2%, #FF0 2%);
      width: 500px;
      height: 50px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
.nota p{
      font-family: tahoma, arial;
      font-weight: 20px;
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="nota">
    <p><b>Nota:</b> observações importantes irão aqui...</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: vou dar uma verificada para ver como esse `linear-gradient` funciona =D

Answer (score 2):

Uma opção usando `linear-gradiente` para poupar mais uma linha de css :)

```css
div {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0f0 0px, #0f0 5px, #ff0 5px);
}
```

```html
  <div>
    <b>Nota:</b> observações importantes irão aqui...
  </div>
```

Comment: boa! só o font-family que o crucial que não poderia ficar sem, mas mesmo assim reduziria uma linha ;)